# Why isn't the array being mutated in this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my first question on Stackoverflow :)

Below, I have set up two functions and I'm trying to use them to mutate the array "nums". But it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong, especially in the last part after the function definitions? I am using higher order functions to learn how they work.

```
function forEach(array, callback) {
    for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    callback(array[i]);
  }
}

function mapWith(array, callback) {
    forEach(array, callback);
}

let nums = [1, 2, 3];
mapWith(nums, item => item+=2);
console.log(nums); //console output: [1, 2, 3]
```

But changing the last part the following way, does show that the array is changing the way I wanted. But why can't I manipulate it directly?

```
let nums = [];
mapWith([1, 2, 3], item => nums.push(item+=2));
console.log(nums); //console output: [3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that you are not saving your returned callback value for each array element. You just need to modify your `forEach()` function like this

```
function forEach(array, callback) {
    for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = callback(array[i]);
  }
}
```

> Side note
>
> Your `mapWith` function is doing nothing but calling your `forEach` function. You could just use `forEach`

Comment: You're totally right. Now I can see why it wasn't working. :)

To the side note: It was part of the exercise for using higher order functions, but I understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

It works correctly, when you call `callback(array[i]);` it passes value to callback function not reference, if you will pass for example an object to `callback` it will be passed as refernce.

An example:

```
const obj = {val: 1};
const modify = (obj) => {
   obj.val += 1;
}

modify(obj);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are basically doing:

```
function callbackFunction (item) {
  return item + 2;
}
let test = 5;
const newNumber = callbackFunction(test);
console.log(test);
console.log(newNumber);
```

You don't mutate the variable `test`, but just return new variable. That's why you are getting the same numbers.

Also, notice you wrote this `mapWith(nums, item => item=+2);` instead of `item += 2`.